# inline style react element width

Tags: css, reactjs, width, inline-styles

I'm trying to create a circular div with a set width. It works fine but once I add more divs than what fits on the screen the circle's width gets overridden. The parent container has `overflow: scroll` set and the div is scrollable.

Here is my Avatar component code

```
 const Avatar= ({contact, email, circle, width, margin, fontSize, fontWeight}) => {
  let style = {}

  if (width) {
    style.width = `${width}px` || '32px'
    style.height = `${width}px` || '32px'
    style.margin = `${margin}px` || '4px'
  }

  if (circle) {
    style.borderRadius = `${width/2}px` || '16px'
  }

  let displayName;


  if (contact && contact.avatar) {
    return (
      <img style={style}
        src={contact.avatar}
        title={contact.FN || contact.wyreId || email}
        alt={contact.FN || contact.wyreId || email}
      />
    )
  } ... removed code that sets displayname

  // default display
  style.color = '#fff';
  style.background = 'orange';
  style.lineHeight = style.height;
  style.textAlign = 'center';
  style.fontSize = fontSize;
  style.fontWeight = fontWeight;
  return (
    <div style={style}>
        {
          displayName || '?'
        }
      </div>
  )
}
```

[Here is an image of the components working as intended.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPYMy.png)
[Here is an image of the components not working as intended.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlybX.png)

when I inspect using dev tools this is the style added to the div for both cases. 
`style=width: 32px; height: 32px; margin: 4px; border-radius: 16px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background: orange; line-height: 32px; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;`

Any idea what can be going wrong

Also just in case here is the style set on the parent div.

```
.horizontalList {
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: -20px;
margin-left: 2%;
margin-right: 2%;
padding-bottom: 10px;
display: inline-flex;
justify-content: center;
height: 60px;
overflow: scroll;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by setting `style.minWidth =`${width}px`|| '32px';` in the Avatar component.

Answer (score 1):

This not react or inline styles issue. Remove property `display: inline-flex` from parent container and add it to  circular divs

Check this: [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/t4y8z18u/)

Comment: Removing inline-flex from the parent only displays the circle divs in individual rows.

Comment: You have to set display: inline-flex to your images (or li-item), whatever you have. Check the link I've added to my answer.